# Yocto: <Package A> rdepends on <Package B> , but it isn't a build dependency? [build-deps]

Tags: linux, yocto

Yocto:   rdepends on  , but it isn't a build dependency? [build-deps]

Getting these warnings for packages in my yocto (thud branch ) build for glib-2.0 for glib-2.0-ptest .

An example :

```
glib-2.0-1_2.58.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: glib-2.0-ptest rdepends on glibc-charmap-invariant, but it isn't a build dependency? [build-deps]
```

This is due to RDEPENDS at https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/glib-2.0/glib.inc?h=thud#n145

Is it a good idea to change

```
RDEPENDS_${PN}-ptest_append_libc-glibc = "\
```

to

```
RRECOMMENDS_${PN}-ptest_append_libc-glibc = "\
```

or

```
DEPENDS_${PN}-ptest_append_libc-glibc = "\
```

Comment: You should probably ask directly to maintainer of the concerned recipe. It could be due to a specific configuration you are using but I would not change the dependencies as you propose since it's only a warning and the consequence of changing it could be worse than the warning itself.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm getting a similar Warning, and I don't know if the package that appears to be a dependency but is not specified explicitly in `DEPENDS`, should be added there or not. Is there a chance you remember how you tackled the problem?